# It's May. How do I send a calendar invite for August?

Tags: ipad, ios, calendar

The iPad calendar app only sends alerts two weeks ahead of time. I want to send an invite now for an event in August.

Answer (score 3):

Alerts and invites are different things. When you invite someone the invite will be sent immediately regardless of the time of the event.